# rpmbuild php package can not create directory permission denied then %install

Tags: php, linux, rpmbuild

I want to custom build a php rpm package, but I have some problem in the `%install` time, errors show as follows:

```sh
Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

+ exit 0
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.JrATF9
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/work/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ '[' /home/work/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/php-7.3.2-1.el7.x86_64 '!=' / ']'
+ rm -rf /home/work/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/php-7.3.2-1.el7.x86_64
++ dirname /home/work/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/php-7.3.2-1.el7.x86_64
+ mkdir -p /home/work/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT
+ mkdir /home/work/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/php-7.3.2-1.el7.x86_64
+ cd php-7.3.2
+ rm -rf /home/work/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/php-7.3.2-1.el7.x86_64
+ /usr/bin/mkdir -p /home/work/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/php-7.3.2-1.el7.x86_64/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731
+ /usr/bin/make install DESTDIR=/home/work/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/php-7.3.2-1.el7.x86_64
mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/local/lib/php': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731': No such file or directory
make: *** [install-modules] Error 1
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.JrATF9 (%install)

RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.JrATF9 (%install)
```

My php Spec file is here:

```sh
Name:           php
Version:        7.3.2
Release:        1%{?dist}

Source0:        %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz

BuildRoot:  %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root

%prep
%setup -q

%build
./configure --enable-fpm --enable-mbstring --with-pdo-mysql --without-sqlite3 --without-pdo-sqlite --with-openssl --with-zlib --with-curl --with-libdir=lib64

make %{?_smp_mflags}

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%{__mkdir} -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731

%make_install

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)

%attr(0755,root,root) %dir /usr/local/lib/php
%attr(0755,root,root) %dir /usr/local/lib/php/extensions
%attr(0755,root,root) %dir /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731
```

How can I create the `/usr/local/lib/php` permission or own the right permission ?

Any help you ?

Comment: You doing this as root or as your regular user account?

Comment: Not root user。Beacause the new Redhat rpmbuid recommend do not use root user  build packge, so I create a non-root user do this。But I found another thing, If I use `make INSTALL_ROOT=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT install `, then it work successfully but use `make DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT install` not. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track by *not* building as `root`! Try replacing the `./configure` call with `%{configure}` which is a macro that will put in all the Red Hat flags they want (like checking for stack overflows, etc) as well as the `DESTDIR` flags and whatnot you need for it all to "just work." You're already (properly) using the `%{make_install}` macro so you're fine there.

I would take out the `mkdir` call because the "`make install`" should cover that.

Comment: There is one things you are right. That's there is no need make dir. So I delete it. When I change the build user to root, then I have changed the `./confgure` to `%configure` and `make install ` to `%make install` ， other things happened ! The softeware be used in the build system, but not in the `buildroot`。this is not right. Later, I found another thing, I search the INSTALL_ROOT micro and DESTDIR micro in the configure file, Only `INSTALL_ROOT` founded.

Comment: No matter use `make install` or `%{make_install}`, all should be add one prefix var like this: `INSTALL_ROOT=%{buildroot} make install`, then It worked. The finnally spec file is here: https://github.com/apptut/common-rpm-specs/blob/master/php.spec

Comment: I said *not* to use `root`. As for `INSTALL_ROOT` vs. `DESDIR`, that means what you are packaging is not following standard GNU convention.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstand. I fixed this, tks!